# zxing android integration crash on some devices , he following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I have integrated Zxing as Library and used in my application. I am calling by

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");     
intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39");
intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

It works fine on most devices but on Some devices like HTC Desire ,GT-I9000 . I am receiving below Error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.Armacell.login/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error
>   inflating class com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error
>   inflating class com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:200)
>   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647) at
>   com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:160)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView.(ViewfinderView.java:62)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500) ... 21
>   more Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):
>   TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070012 a=-1 r=0x7f070012} at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681) at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:1895) at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:1844) ... 25 more

I am also receiving this warning on Capture.xml file in zxing source - 
"**The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView**"

I am requesting all to help in this case. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Got Solution on My Own.

The Issue is regarding Culture. I have change default "values". make "values-de" to "values". That crashes Zxing on device that have German culture.

I don't know why it was working but now i have made english as default and it working now :)

Comment: This is nothing to do with the error you posted. This means you had a different problem: you removed default English strings, move German strings into their place, and then later did not update `values` with new strings you added elsewhere. Or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is all wrong -- you're including our Android code in your app. It's not necessary, not encouraged, and you haven't done it correctly either. Please delete all code you copied from `android/` into your project.

(In fact we strongly discourage you from copying and pasting like you have.)

Instead you should just be using code in `android-integration` and nothing else. You're not actually using the integrator code even!

Please start over from: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: but why your Capture.xml shows this Error in Eclipse
**"The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView"**

Comment: Ours doesn't have any such error. Your copy does because you have done this incorrectly

Comment: When i open Capture.xml Eclipse Shows me that

**"The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView"**

Can you please help me out in this case, I have downloaded this android source from svn

Comment: Still your error, and it means exactly what it says. Why would I help you do what you aren't meaning to do? Read the link I sent you are making this too hard.